# Converting object to datetime format in python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Below is the first row of my csv DateTime column:

```
Mon Nov 02 20:37:10 GMT+00:00 2015
```

The DateTime column is currently an object and I want to convert it to datetime format so that I can get the date to appear as 2015-11-02 and I will create a separate column for the time.

The code I am using to convert the column to date time format is:

```
for item, frame in df['DateTime'].iteritems():
     datetime.datetime.strptime(df['DateTime'], "%a-%b-%d-%H-%M-%S-%Z-%Y")
```

I am getting this error:

```
> TypeError: must be str, not Series
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @bernie: that yields `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'`,

Comment: Ah, thanks. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
```

For example,

```
pd.to_datetime('Mon Nov 02 20:37:10 GMT+00:00 2015')
```

produces `Timestamp('2015-11-02 20:37:10')`.

Comment: Any idea what to do where there is a huge list, and one time is nan? Should i first try to find  and edit/change that one value to something or is there a nice trick?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to pass **errors** parameter as per below and its application

**df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], errors='coerce')**

*errors{‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’*

1. If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
2. If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN.
3. If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to further add to 'Alicia Garcia-Raboso', that after conversion we may need to extract Year, Month . We can do this by df ['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].dt.year, and so on. This is especially useful when dealing with dataframes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35546046)