# Function to check type datetime for cells in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a large data set with two datetime columns and as I’m trying to clean it, I created a function that apply to each cell of these two columns:

```
#dropoff_datetime
def date_time_dropoff(cell):
    if pd.isnull(cell) == True:
        return('Missing Date Time dropoff')
    elif type(cell) == datetime.datetime:
        return ('Clean Date Time dropoff')
    elif type(cell) != datetime.datetime:
        return ('Type error Date Time dropoff')
```

When I run it first time on my dataframe, it returns that the cells have the wrong type (indeed, I see that it is of type object when I use df.dtypes). So next I convert the df using pandas method:

```
df2['Statue_dropoff_datetime'] = df['dropoff_datetime'].apply(date_time_dropoff)
```

and run the function again, but it stills return Type error  because it is not type datetim.datetime. However, once I use df.dtypes after the conversion I obtain the correct datetimetype:

`dropoff_datetime        datetime64[ns]`

Without success, I tried answers suggested for similar questions dealing with convesion, mainly:
[Converting object column in pandas dataframe to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898826/converting-object-column-in-pandas-dataframe-to-datetime)
[Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)
[Converting object to datetime format in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333954/converting-object-to-datetime-format-in-python)
[How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Btw, when I import at the beginning, I use:
`import datetime`

Here's my df:

```
dropoff_datetime
2020-06-10 11:16:00
2020-06-21 11:53:06
2020-06-09 13:25:21
2020-06-01 19:06:05

#dropoff_datetime
def date_time_dropoff(cell):
    if pd.isnull(cell) == True:
        return('Date Time dropoff missing')
    elif type(cell) == datetime:
        return ('Date Time dropoff clean')
    elif type(cell) != datetime:
        return ('Date Time dropoff Type error')

df1[‘Statue_dropoff_datetime'] = df['dropoff_datetime'].apply(date_time_dropoff)
```

and when I print:

```
print(pd.value_counts(df1.values.ravel()))
Type error Date Time dropoff    47703
```

while using `df.dtypes` gives:

```
df.dtypes
dropoff_datetime        datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Could you please make sure to have a complete working example so it's easier for others to reproduce the problem? Thanks!
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is it better now ? @fischmalte

Comment: related: [Python pandas: how to obtain the datatypes of objects in a mixed-datatype column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64195782/10197418)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, to check if an object is of a certain type, use `isinstance`. So your function could look like

```
def date_time_dropoff(cell):
    if pd.isnull(cell):
        return('Date Time dropoff missing')
    elif isinstance(cell, datetime):
        return ('Date Time dropoff clean')
    else:
        return ('Date Time dropoff Type error')
```

But I think you can do this more easily only with the call to `isinstance`, which you use to check for type `datetime.datetime`. A check for `pd.Timestamp` would be the "more narrow" criterion, cleaning out datetime.datetime as well.

**Ex:**

Given a DataFrame with a mixed dtype column,

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'mixedcol': ['2021-01-01', datetime(2021,1,1), 
                                pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01'), 'something else', 42, np.nan]})
```

you can mask all datetime values like

```
m = df['mixedcol'].apply(lambda v: isinstance(v, datetime))
```

...and use the mask to set all other values to `NaN`. Then convert to datetime and you should be where you want to be:

```
df['cleaned'] = pd.to_datetime(np.where(m, df['mixedcol'], np.NaN))

# df['cleaned']
# 0          NaT
# 1   2021-01-01
# 2   2021-01-01
# 3          NaT
# 4          NaT
# 5          NaT
# Name: cleaned, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: The mask works to replace by None but my function still doesn’t recognize the datetime values after the conversion. @MrFuppes

Comment: @Hibou: use `isinstance` in your function, not `type ==`

Comment: It works ! Could you please add it to the answer for others ? @MrFuppes

Comment: @Hibou: sure, added.