# How to retain the data type datetime64 with the format ("%m/%d/%Y") in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Please, wait before marking it as a duplicate.
These posts 
 [How to change the datetime format in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas) 
 [Converting object to datetime format in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333954/converting-object-to-datetime-format-in-python)
answered my question partially.
Sample data:
date1:
04/26/2012
02/16/2006
11/26/2017
...
`dtype: object`

I converted an object type to `datetime64` like this by following the above-linked post:

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

The code returned results in the format `%Y-%m-%d`. `format='%m/%d/%Y'` didn't preserve the original form which was `%m/%d/%Y`. However, the dtype was changed to `datetime64[ns]` from `object` which I wanted.

So, I added another line of code to get the original format based on the answers from the above-linked posts.

```
df['date1'] = df['date1'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Again, the column's data type was converted back to `object`. But, I need to retain the `datetime64` data type.

How to preserve the original formatting, `'%m/%d/%Y'` with the `dtype: datetime64`?

Comment: Do you need to retain the format whilst working with `datetune64[ns]`?  Could you work with the datetime type, then convert to desired format for presenting once you have finished manipulating the data?

Comment: I could work the way you suggested. But, I wanted to know if there are any solutions to the problem.

Comment: `datetime` values do not have a format.  They are strictly binary objects that store a date value.  The format only comes in to play when a `datetime` column is printed.  So, leave your values in binary while you work with the data.  When you need to print a report or something, THEN you can specify a format.